# How do front-end Javascript frameworks (like Vue.js) use custom elements without using Web Components?

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, dom

I realize this a beginner question. I'm experienced on the back-end, but not on the front-end. Here is an example Vue.js application:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>My first Vue app</title>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <ol>
        <!-- Create an instance of the todo-item component -->
        <todo-item></todo-item>
      </ol>
    </div>

    <script>
      // Define a new component called todo-item
      Vue.component("todo-item", {
        template: "<li>This is a todo</li>"
      });
      var app = new Vue({
        el: "#app",
      });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I don't understand how any browser accepts this because `<todo-item>` is not a valid HTML element. I know the "Web Components" spec exist, but [Vue's documentation says it's not using Web Components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Relation-to-Custom-Elements).

(My *guess* is that it uses something simple like `document.getElementsByTagName('todo-item');` and replaces elements with valid HTML ones. Part of me is surprised that custom elements get added to the DOM at all to allow this method to work.)

Comment: This really isn't a good question for stackoverflow and it's likely to get downvoted (but not by me, I don't think any question is a "silly" question). https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is also a hard question to answer without writing an essay. Perhaps you should spend a bit of time researching how browsers work and how front end tooling (e.g. webpack) works. As to your specific issue, browsers don't validate HTML; rather they try to be as permissive as possible.

Comment: Most modern apps will fail any HTML validation. But the bottom line is that browsers don't care about that.